# How can I get button-click-navigation and touch-slide-navigation at the same time in React Native?

Tags: react-native

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiuCN.gif) is some part of the YouTube video.(using createStackNavigator in React Native).
How can I achieve this kind of effect in React Native( Navigation by button click and touch slide at the same time ) ?
I followed this video but it works such as fadeIn, fadeOut effect in jQuery. 
The author of this video installed "yarn add react-navigation@2.0.0-beta.3".
I installed it but it gave me error. So I used this. "yarn add react-navigation".
This is the whole code of `App.js`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

class ScreenComponentOne extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          borderWidth: 25,
          borderColor: '#f00',
        }}
      >
        <Button
          title="Go to the screen two"
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteNameTwo')
          }}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
class ScreenComponentTwo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          borderWidth: 25,
          borderColor: '#f0f',
        }}
      >
        <Button
          title="Go to the screen one"
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate({routeName:'RouteNameOne', transitionStyle: 'inverted'})
          }}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  RouteNameOne: {
    screen:ScreenComponentOne,
    navigationOptions:{
      header:null,
    }
  },
  RouteNameTwo: {
    screen:ScreenComponentTwo,
    navigationOptions:{
      header:null,
    }
  },
},
{
  initialRouteName:"RouteNameOne"
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

I'd like to get touch-slide-navigation and button-click-navigation at the same time.
The module that I installed is as follows:

-yarn install

-yarn add react-navigation (for createAppContainer)

-yarn add react-navigation-stack (for createStackNavigator)

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: With React-Navigation, slide & touch and button automatically works with StackNavigator only on iOS because iOS's use-case works like that. If you want to works with both iOS and Android. You need to handle the Swipe for Android as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I am using Android not iOS.
So how can I get the effect mentioned above in Android?
Can I get the wanted effect by using Swipe?
If so kindly tell me how to get this effect.

Comment: Actually I have no solid solution for that, you need to research about Android StackNavigation Swipe feature. Have fun :)

Comment: Dear FreakyCoder, Really thank you.